# In mySQL, how do I return a list of grouped items limited to a certain number of groups + unique items

Tags: sql, mysql

Okay, so this one may be difficult but I will do my best to explain. Bear with me...

I have a table with multiple columns as follows.

ITEM_ID    -  GROUP_ID
1     -          null
2      -         null
3       -        null
4        -        3
5        -        3
6        -        3
7        -        21
8        -         6
9        -        21
10       -        21
11       -        21
12       -         4
13       -         4
15       -         6
16       -         6
17       -         6
19       -         3

I want to go into this table and return a list such that:

1.) Each item is separate.
2.) Each item is grouped by the group ID.
3.) The result is limited to 5 groups total with each item that is null counted as a single unique group.
4.) When a group is returned, all objects that have the same group number are returned.

With this example I want to return:

1       -        null
2       -        null
3        -       null
4        -        3
5        -        3
6        -        3
19       -        3
7        -        21
9        -        21
10       -        21
11       -        21

So items 1,2 and 3 each count as 1 returned group apiece for a total of 3 returned groups.
Items 4,5,6 and 19 are all group 3 and count as one returned group bringing our total to 4 groups returned. Items 7,9,10 and 11 are all group 21 and count as one returned group bringing our total to 5 returned groups at which point no more groups or single items (which count as groups) are returned.

I am usually pretty good with SQL but this one completely eludes me.

Thanks everyone!!!

Comment: Okay, so I am continuing to work on this and may have something useful. The following code will correctly return the row_counter variable while sorting how I want it.  

set @count := 0, @group := '';  
SELECT ITEM_ID, GROUP_ID,   
@count := IF (@group not like GROUP_ID OR GROUP_ID like "" OR GROUP_ID is null, @count +1,@count) AS row_counter,  
@group := GROUP_ID as dummy  
FROM `myTable`    
ORDER BY GROUP_ID    

This gets the group count correctly but doesn't have a way of stopping once the variable row_counter reaches 5. I tried using 'WHERE row_counter <= 5' but this errors out.

Comment: Okay, my apologies, no clue why that didn't format correctly and doesn't seem to want to let me format it...

Comment: Oh, and I don't want to use a temp table if I can avoid it. The query may well normally return thousands of results and is run often. I want to keep it limited to running only on what it needs to run on.

Thanks again!

Comment: What are you ordering the groups by to limit them to 5?  From the example it looks like nulls first and then ascending group_id.

Comment: Dan, thanks for the question. I am indeed ordering them by group_id with nulls coming first. Each null will increment the counter. Each group_id that has not been previously counted will also increment the counter. Once that counter hits 5 I want the query to stop. I know that I could use a nested select but the inner table could potentially by huge thus making my query painfully slow.

Comment: To be precise, in the above example code I gave the return result would be: (1 - null),
(2 - null),
(3 - null),
(4 - 3),
(5 - 3),
(6 - 3),
(19 - 3), 
(12 - 4),
(13 - 4)

Which is fine. The top 5 groups are found and returned in their entirety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return what you are asking for.  The inner subqueries simply filter the nulls and assign a unique "key" (a negative id number).  These are "limited" to the first five unique group ids and are then joined against the a copy of the subquery to return the records we need.  The outer subquery is then used to print the result set in the manner reuquested.

```
select a.item_id, case when a.group_id <= 0 then null else a.group_id end group_id 
from (
    select distinct group_id, item_id from test.so_test where group_id is not null 
    union
    (select  -item_id, item_id from test.so_test where group_id is null)
)  a inner join (
    select distinct group_id from test.so_test where group_id is not null 
    union
    (select  -item_id from test.so_test where group_id is null)
    order by group_id limit 0, 5
) b on a.group_id = b.group_id
order by case when a.group_id <= 0 then null else a.group_id end, a.item_id;
```

Comment: Thank you, took me a minute to see what you were doing but once I realized I could have kicked myself :)

Thank you very much for the help!